How can i make a transaction where I don't pay Fees
I'm trying to make a transaction where a user can claim x amount of tokens, without me (project's wallet) having to pay anything
This is the setup:
I'm trying to send a user 100 $TOKEN without me creating a new UTXO (so i don't have to send dust ADA along with it)
at the same time i want the user to pay the transaction fee not me.
does the setup in the attachment work? if yes how can i do that in mesh?
if no what's wrong with it, and how can i fix it. any help would be appreciated


I think the wording is a bit off - since you always create a new UTXO when you spend some of your tokens in the transaction - but what you're trying to achieve is entirely feasible and your illustration explains it well
Fees must be payed, but it does not matter which party ultimately pays them, as long as you get both to sign the tx.
You could additionally increase the throughput by splitting up the 1000 $Token on multiple UTXOs.
You also don't necessarily need a smart contract for this type of transaction. Your project backend can compose the transaction, and then have both parties (your project and the user) sign it 

Got it thanks, but in this case, who pays the fees? which signer, both?

In your case it's the claiming user (blue) who pays the fees.
That's probably also the person who initiates the transaction on a website or so - so its like the "default" I'd say for most apps, if I'm not mistaken.
But in practice, you can compose the transaction any way you want; just subtract the calculated fees from any of the outputs (change utxos). When both parties agree (and sign the tx), it should work fine.
(also keep in mind that the UTXO with the new $Token balance needs to have a certain amount of min Ada in it as well)

I really do not think that is possible. Forcing the payment of fees is how the Cardano network avoids DDOS attacks.

Yea but the user is paying fee for the transaction. Sorry if my wording was inaccurate, it meant that the project's wallet not pay anything, and the user pays the transaction fees.
